# How Can I Pass Platform specific data from one platform device/driver to another platform device/driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have two platform device/driver - say Pdriver1 and Pdriver2.
I want to access platform specific data of Pdriver1 from Pdriver2.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: How computers with these drivers are connected?

Comment: I have registered both drivers by using platform_device_registered and platform_driver_registered API's

Comment: Are both drivers running on the same computer or on different ones?

Comment: yes both drivers running on same computer.
I have declared one global structure 
struct test {
 int a;
};

Now in Probe function of pdriver1 i am initializing global structure e.g.
static int test_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
 struct test *temp = kmalloc(sizeof(struct test),GFP_KERNEL);
 if(temp == NULL)
 {
  return -1;
 }
 temp->a =10;
}

Now i want to access this structure value in pdriver2

Answer (score 1):

In module `pdriver1` you should register external symbol with `EXPORT_SYMBOL` in order to allow other modules to access it.

Then, you should specify `pdriver1` as a dependency of `pdriver2`, so modprobe will load `pdriver1` before `pdriver2`. Then in `pdriver2` you could access exported symbol in `pdriver1`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I got this.
I have another question.
Is it possible to access private data of pdriver1 from pdriver2 ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but think, this is impossible. All exported symbols are accessible for all other modules (with proper license). To protect your data, you could don't provide prototypes of the function in public header. But if prototype is known, module can access it. The other way is to manage obscure security system. Why do you need hide your symbols?